# cluster my data and testing of input

Tags: cluster-analysis

cluster the given data and use any retrieval algorithm to show output as shown below.
(any clustering algorithm)
Euclidean distance may be used for finding closest cases.

let a data file  containing input vectors like

```
caseid  f1  f2  f3    f4 
1       30  45  9.5   1500

2       35  45  8     1600
3       38  47  10    1550 

4       32  50  9.5   1800

..
..
..
t1      30   45   9.5   1500(target)
```

output should like

```
NO.  f1  f2  f3   f4
t1   30  45  9.5  1500 (target) 
21   35  45  10   1500(1st closest to target)
39   35  50  8   1500 (2nd closes)
56   35  42  9.5 1500  (3rd closes)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classic **nearest neighbor query** to me, not like clustering.

Also I'd be careful with using Euclidean distance here. A difference of 1 in attribute f1 does not look like it is equal to a difference of 1 in attribute f4. The values seem to have a completely different magnitude.